# What's the difference between "Wood Filler" and "Floor patch & Smoothing Compound"?

Tags: bathroom, wood, flooring

I'm getting ready to repair a [small dry rot spot in my bathroom floor](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61934/how-can-i-seal-this-dryrot-spot-to-prevent-it-from-getting-worse) and am conflicted on which product to use.

When I visited my local big box store, they had a couple options:

1) High Performance Wood Filler:

[image]

2) Premixed Patch n'Level:

[image]

What's the difference between these two types of products? When is it appropriate/recommended to use one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leveling compound pictured is used underneath a finish floor. The minwax/ bondo solution would provide a durable fix that you could walk on. So I guess it depends on whether you'll throw something over the top of the fix...

Comment: At this point I'm just planning to buy some time until the next bathroom remodel.  Planning to just put a vinyl patch over it for now.

Comment: DEFINITELY use the Minwax filler. It will be much more resistant to the moist conditions presented by the location of your patch. That leveling compound is not resistant to moisture.